# Conditional Variance for a subset of i.i.d. Bernouilli random variables

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I would need some help to compute a conditional variance for a problem linked to actuarial science.

Assume that we model the mortality of a population over one year by a sum of i.i.d. Bernouilli random variables : $I=I_1 + I_2 + ...+I_n $ with $I_i$ is a Bernouilli with $\mathbb{P}[I_i=1]=p $ and $\mathbb{P}[I_i=0]=1-p $.

Consider now that a subset of the population belongs to an insurance company and it is represented by $S=I_1 + I_2 + ...+I_m $ with $m\leq n$.

Now, in order to price the contract, we need to determine the following quantities:

- $\mathbb{E}[S|I]$
- $\mathbb{V}[S|I]$

At first sight, I would say $\mathbb{E}[S|I]$=$\frac{m}{n}I$ but I have no idea for the variance...

Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 5):

By symmetry,
$$I=E[I_1 + \cdots + I_n \mid I] = E[I_1 \mid I] + \cdots + E[I_n \mid I] = n E[I_i \mid I]$$
$$E[I_i \mid I] = \frac{1}{n} I$$
for each $i$, so
$$E[S \mid I] = m E[I_1 \mid I] = \frac{m}{n}I.$$

---

Again, using symmetry
$$
I^2 = E[(I_1+\cdots+I_n)^2 \mid I]
= nE[I_1^2 \mid I] + n(n-1) E[I_1 I_2 \mid I]
= I + n(n-1) E[I_1 I_2 \mid I]
$$
So for $i \ne j$,
$$
E[I_i I_j \mid I]=E[I_1 I_2 \mid I] = \frac{1}{n(n-1)}I(I-1).
$$

So,
\begin{align}
Var(S \mid I)
&= E[S^2 \mid I] - E[S \mid I]^2\\
&= E[(I_1+\cdots+I_m)^2 \mid I] - \frac{m^2}{n^2} I^2\\
&= mE[I_1^2 \mid I] + m(m-1) E[I_1 I_2 \mid I] - \frac{m^2}{n^2} I^2\\
&= \frac{m}{n} I + \frac{m(m-1)}{n(n-1)}I(I-1) - \frac{m^2}{n^2} I^2\\
&= \frac{m}{n} I \left(1 + \frac{m-1}{n-1} (I-1) - \frac{m}{n} I\right)\\
&= \frac{m}{n} I \left(\frac{n-m}{n-1} - \frac{n-m}{n(n-1)} I\right)\\
&= \frac{m(n-m)}{n(n-1)} I \left(1 - \frac{1}{n} I\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much ! That was exactly what I needed !